# Group By And Two Counts

Tags: c#, beginner, entity-framework

I'd like to know if there's any better way to write this query:

```
(from a in Context.Pages
join b in Context.Visitors on a.PageID equals b.PageFK
join c in Context.Visits on b.VisitorID equals c.VisitorFK
join d in Context.Signups on c.VisitID equals d.VisitFK
where
d.DateOptinUtc.HasValue && a.UserFK == USER_ID
group d by new { a.PageID, a.DateCreated, a.BaseName, a.Name }
into g
select
new ListReport
 {
     DateCreated = g.Key.DateCreated,
     BaseName = g.Key.BaseName,
     Id = g.Key.PageID,
     Name = g.Key.Name,
     Optins = g.Count(),
     Views =
         (from h in Context.Visits
          where
              h.Visitors.PageFK == g.Key.PageID
          select h).Count()
 }).AsQueryable();
```

Are there any performance issues writing subqueries like these? I don't how I can get that value from the groupby.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily look bad.  What does the generated SQL look like? EF may have optimized this pretty well and the database's query optimizer may further optimize it. Is there a performance problem at all?

Comment: There is no performance problem atm as we are in development stage. I was just curious / want to know it there was a better way. Thanks!

Comment: A (micro) optimization might be to collect the page counts separately and join these in memory with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the performance issues you should make the query more readable by using relevant variable names instead of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `g`, and `h`.  In addition, the ambiguous `ListReport` class name should be changed to something more specific like `PageUsage` since it contains information about a page and how many times it has been viewed/used for signup.

```
(from page in Context.Pages
join visitor in Context.Visitors on page.PageID equals visitor.PageFK
join visit in Context.Visits on visitor.VisitorID equals visit.VisitorFK
join signup in Context.Signups on visit.VisitID equals signup.VisitFK
where
signup.DateOptinUtc.HasValue && page.UserFK == USER_ID
group signup by new { page.PageID, page.DateCreated, page.BaseName, page.Name }
into signupsByPage
select
new PageUsage
 {
     DateCreated = signupsByPage.Key.DateCreated,
     BaseName = signupsByPage.Key.BaseName,
     Id = signupsByPage.Key.PageID,
     Name = signupsByPage.Key.Name,
     Optins = signupsByPage.Count(),
     Views =
         (from subVisit in Context.Visits
          where
              subVisit.Visitors.PageFK == signupsByPage.Key.PageID
          select subVisit).Count()
 }).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this query to bring every record on table Pages? I tried to use defaultifempty thing but did not work as expected.

Comment: It worked now but if i use any where clause using signup it stops working